# How do you extract css imports from submodules with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-modules

I'm trying to create a React application with multiple entries using `webpack` and `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

My config file looks like this,

```
const commonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let config = {
  entry: {
    app: './client/app.entry.js',
    signIn: './client/sign-in.entry.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: './server/public',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: extractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'client'],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },

  plugins: [
    new commonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common.js'),
    new extractTextPlugin('styles.css', { allChunks: true })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

My problem is that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` only includes imported css files from the entry chunks, and not from submodules of the entry chunks.

So if `app.entry.js` has

```
import "./app-style.css";
import "./sub-module"; // This module has import "./sub-style.css";
```

then the styles from `app-style.css` gets bundled but not the styles from `sub-style.css`.

I haven't had this issue before when there's only been one entry file, so I'm wondering if having multiple entries requires another setup?

Something to also take into consideration is the use of CSSModules by the way the `css-loader` is used, which also could be a factor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve similar problem, and i think it will be nice idea to document the solution and thoughts for those who has the same questions.

TextExtract plugin can work with chunks that have to be configured with commonchunks plugin, enable chunks support:

```
// Configuration of the extract plugin with chunks and naming
new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", {  allChunks: true })
```

It's all ) Next thing is just configuration of the chunks (webpack is very flexible tool, everyone configure it for own needs. For an instance i'll show how i configure "vendour.css" and "application.css" build configuration based on "imports")

```
// Vendour chunks definition for vendor css
entry: {
  vendor : ['./css/vendour.sass']
```

Example of entrypoint file.js

```
import "./css/vendor.sass"
import "./css/application.sass"
```

After build, webpack will create vendor.css (where you export vendour things with `@import "~vendormodules/sass/alla"`) and application.css files.

Thanks,